# Proving maclaurin polynom of a function and working with sums.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f,g$ be a derivatible functions $n$ times.

And let: 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k, \sum_{k=0}^{n}b_kx^k
$$

Be maclaurin polynoms of $f,g$ at that order.

Prove that: 
$$
(*)\sum_{k=0}^{n}(\sum_{j=0}^{k}a_jb_{k-j})x^k
$$

Is the maclaurin polynom of: 
$$
f(x)g(x)
$$

---

### What i tried:

In order to prove, i think need to show that: 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)g(x) - \sum_{k=0}^{n}(\sum_{j=0}^{k}a_jb_{k-j})x^k}{x^2} = 0 
$$

Namely i show that the remainder is going to zero at $x \to 0$ (meclurian so $a = 0$)

I think its quite resonable that i will also need to use the facts (from the same logic) that: 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)- \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k}{x^2} = 0 
$$

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{g(x)- \sum_{k=0}^{n}b_kx^k}{x^2} = 0 
$$

Therefore i think my need is an algebric problem, working with the sums to get to identical terms.

Yet, im not good at it therefore i would like if someone can explain the conccept i need to think of in order to work and change those sums.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean Maclaurin?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1967096/545344), even though this is the infinite version the idea is in the visual provided.