# Proof of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_nt^n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_kt^k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{n-k}b_k)t^n$

Tags: summation

How to prove this identity?
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_nt^n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_kt^k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{n-k}b_k)t^n$$
I found it on a textbook but there was no proof...

Comment: Can you prove it term wise? IE What is the coefficient of $ t^2$ on the LHS? and on the RHS?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/934835/42969